# Xmega ADC ground as internal input

Tags: adc, xmega

Someone knows if it's possible to set the internal ground as input in the ATXMega256A3BU? I need it to find the zero offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is not possible.

---

I have used the 16/32A4, 64B3, 128A3 and 16D4. None of them have this capability. I always dedicate a separate ADC NEG pin for GND and measure differentially against it. But it also lets you measure the ground offset.

In case you don't have any spara pins and/or you already manufactured the board, there's probably no easy way for you...

Comment: May be selecting the DAC input and give it the 0 value? Or it also may be affected by an offset error?

Comment: I haven't used the DAC yet, so I cannot tell if, or to what extent, the offset error is significant in such case.